# Iterating through JSON object with Angular 2 ngFor

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Before I write a service to get json, I just want to use some dummy json to test the front end. What's the correct way to iterate through json with ngFor? I tried the code below with a simple interface.

In the component.ts file (ngOnInit()):

```
var jsonSample = {
    "name": "sample1",
    "content": [
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Test",
      "value": "45"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "Test2",
      "value": "60",
    }]
}

var items: Array<IContent> = jsonSample.content;
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<tr *ngFor='let content of items'>
      <td>{{content.name | lowercase}}</td>
      <td>{{content.id}}</td>
      <td>{{content.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Should I be trying to use JSON.parse instead?

Comment: "service to get json" you mean http response?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question .. Why don't you use jsonSample['content'] in your template ?

Comment: Where in your component are you declaring `var items`? Don't you want that to be an instance property? Templates cannot pick up variables, only component properties.

Comment: @suraj I didn't word that well. I'm doing the backend as well, so I meant the API that I'd call to get json.

Answer (score 0):

Your `*ngFor` looks fine as far as json object traversal is concerned.
You do not need to do `JSON.parse` here as you have set an object directly.

In the case of receiving response from a service check [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html). You will be doing `res.json()` to parse and get json data from the `Response` object.

Answer (score 0):

@torazaburo got it. I just had to change:

```
var items: Array<IContent> = jsonSample.content;
```

to

```
items: IContent[];
this.items = jsonSample.content;
```